# bash "clear" command behaving strangely after git-credential-osxkeychain installation

Tags: git, bash, terminal, osx-mountain-lion

I am a new web programmer setting up a Rails environment on my MacBook Air (Mountain Lion).  I have just started Hartl's Rails tutorial.

I have installed the latest version of git and I used the following instructions to set up password caching: https://help.github.com/articles/set-up-git.  Everything seemed to be working okay.  Got my repository up and running and was able to push a branch to github.

But now, whenever I type `$ clear` into the command line to clear the screen, bash returns:

```
usage: git credential-osxkeychain <get|store|erase>
```

and does not clear the screen.  What happened to the `$ clear` command??

I have no idea why this is happening, whether it's an isolated problem or if it is indicative of a more widespread error in my setup.  Typing `$ which clear`shows clear in /usr/local/bin/clear. If anyone knows what is going on, please help!

UPDATE - MORE INFORMATION!!

Actually, @chrisaycock was correct, there is a `clear` command in usr/bin.  When I execute that command directly (`/usr/bin/clear`), it works as expected.  However, the `clear` command in usr/local/bin is the one that is giving me problems.  Also, `which clear` only returns `usr/local/bin` and ignores the `usr/bin` (Is this because the latter is a bash include?)  Maybe it's a $PATH problem?  I have pasted my .bash_profile and .bashrc files below.  However, when I `echo $PATH` I get a lot of unexpected paths.  I assume it is from the included .rvm stuff from the .bash_profile but I am not sure.  If there's someone out there with some insight, I could use some help understanding (1) whether my problem with the `clear` command is a $PATH problem, (2) how to fix it, whether it's a $PATH issue or not and (3) why `echo $PATH` returns such a long list of paths (suspect the .rvm include, but want to confirm).  Thanks, everyone who's commented so far!

**echo $PATH**

```
    /Users/NAME/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195@rails3tutorial2ndEd/bin:/Users/NAME/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195@global/bin:/Users/NAME/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p195/bin:/Users/NAME/.rvm/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin
```

**.bashrc**

```
    PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin # Add RVM to PATH for scripting

    esource ~/.git-prompt.sh # Load in the git branch prompt script.

    export CLICOLOR=1
    export LSCOLORS=GxFxCxDxBxegedabagaced

    PS1="\w\$(__git_ps1) $ "

    ### Added by the Heroku Toolbelt
    export PATH="/usr/local/heroku/bin:$PATH"
```

**.bash_profile**

```
 export PATH=/usr/local/mysql/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin

[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM into a shell session *as a function*

source ~/.git-prompt.sh # Load in the git branch prompt script.

export CLICOLOR=1
export LSCOLORS=GxFxCxDxBxegedabagaced

PS1="\w\$(__git_ps1) $ "
```

Comment: I'm surprised that `clear` is in `/usr/local/bin` rather than `/usr/bin`. Is there a `clear` in the latter directory?

Comment: Try executing `reset`.

Comment: @kirelagin - Tried `reset` but I'm still having the same problem.
@chrisaycock - I was surprised as well.  No `clear` command in usr/bin where you might expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(1) There is the `/usr/bin/clear` (which you want) and the `/usr/local/bin/clear` (which you don't want). `which clear` returns the one which would be executed; `which -a clear` returns both. Since the command first found when searching the directories in $PATH is executed, and `/usr/local/bin` precedes `/usr/bin` here, it's `/usr/local/bin/clear`.

(2) You can fix this e. g. by reversing the order of `/usr/local/bin` and `/usr/bin` in $PATH, or by deleting or renaming `/usr/local/bin/clear`.

(3) The front part of $PATH (`/Users/NAME/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195@rails3tutorial2ndEd/bin:/Users/NAME/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195@global/bin:/Users/NAME/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p195/bin:/Users/NAME/.rvm/bin:`) seems to come from the .rvm script; the rear part of $PATH (`/usr/local/mysql/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin`) comes from the first line of `.bash_profile` (here you could change the order of `/usr/local/bin` and `/usr/bin`).